# How can I display this in the DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I am trying to split a paragraph and make all words have a span but it only shows the last word in the DOM but when I log it to the console it shows what I want.

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const text = document.querySelector('p');
const allText = text.innerHTML.split(' ');
allText.forEach((elem) => {
  text.innerHTML = `<span>${elem}</span>`;
  console.log(text.innerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.map return array, .forEach just iterate the element and not mandatory to returns anything. You can join string in .forEach like given:

```
let htmlTemplate = "";
array.forEach(obj=>{ htmlTemplate+=`<span>${obj}</span>` });
text.innerHTML = htmlTemplate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map` instead, to construct an array of `<span>` HTML strings, then join them and assign them back to the `<p>`:

```
const p = document.querySelector("p");
p.innerHTML = p.textContent
  .map(elem => `<span>${elem}</span>`)
  .join('');
```

You need to assign to the `.innerHTML` all at once, rather than in every iteration of the loop. (or, if you do do so inside the loop, use `+=` instead of `=` so that the existing HTML doesn't get lost, and set the initial HTML to the empty string beforehand)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more efficiently with replace:

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const text = document.querySelector('p');
const text.innerHTML = text.innerText.replace(/(\S+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

`\S`: matches any character that is not a white space

`+`: words with at least 1 character long